# I cannot open C++ projects in Linux - UnrealEngine 4.27

Tags: linux, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

[image]

I'm trying to open a unreal project, which is c++ project. I say this to rebuild alt text and gettin this error. alt text Afther that windows it opens an error log window and refers me to open from external file manager in linux.

I tried to go back to UnrealEngne build directory and reapplied make command it compiled some new things. Actually error message wouldn't change

[image]

I'm putting error log into attachments.link text And also log of third window link text

[image]

My distro is Fedora 35, I previously tried on 34 as well, details is that:

```
LSB Version: :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch

Distributor ID: Fedora

Description: Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)

Release: 35

Codename: ThirtyFive
```

`Linux uludag 5.14.14-300.fc35.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 20 16:14:50 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I installed clang clang++ all build tools inside but it didn't work as well.

```
Log file open, 11/03/21 13:44:32
LogConsoleResponse: Display: Failed to find resolution value strings in scalability ini. Falling back to default.
LogConsoleResponse: Display: Failed to find resolution value strings in scalability ini. Falling back to default.
LogInit: Display: Running engine for game: BullCowGame
LogPlatformFile: Not using cached read wrapper
LogTaskGraph: Started task graph with 5 named threads and 26 total threads with 3 sets of task threads.
LogStats: Stats thread started at 0.128415
LogICUInternationalization: ICU TimeZone Detection - Raw Offset: +3:00, Platform Override: ''
LogInit: Display: Loading text-based GConfig....
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MeshPainting
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin XGEController
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Paper2D
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin EnvironmentQueryEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AISupport
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LiveLink
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LightPropagationVolume
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GameplayCameras
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CameraShakePreviewer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OodleData
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OodleNetwork
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AnimationSharing
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CLionSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GitSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin KDevelopSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin NullSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PerforceSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PixWinPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PlasticSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CodeLiteSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PluginUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PropertyAccessNode
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SubversionSourceControl
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin RiderSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin TextureFormatOodle
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin UObjectPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin VisualStudioCodeSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin XCodeSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AssetManagerEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CryptoKeys
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin DataValidation
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CurveEditorTools
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin FacialAnimation
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GameplayTagsEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryMode
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MacGraphicsSwitching
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PluginBrowser
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SpeedTreeImporter
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MobileLauncherProfileWizard
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin DatasmithContent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin VariantManagerContent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AlembicImporter
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AutomationUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin BackChannel
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin VisualStudioSourceCodeAccess
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosCloth
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosClothEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosNiagara
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChaosSolverPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CharacterAI
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MaterialAnalyzer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryCache
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryProcessing
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GeometryCollectionPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MotoSynth
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OpenImageDenoise
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PlanarCut
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PlatformCrypto
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PythonScriptPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SkeletalReduction
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ProxyLODPlugin
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Niagara
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LuminPlatformFeatures
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeap
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MLSDK
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeapPassableWorld
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeapMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MagicLeapLightEstimation
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin TcpMessaging
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LevelSequenceEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ActorSequence
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MatineeToLevelSequence
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin UdpMessaging
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin TemplateSequence
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystem
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemNull
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ActorLayerUtilities
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LauncherChunkInstaller
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidPermission
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AppleImageUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ArchVisCharacter
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AppleMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AssetTags
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AudioCapture
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CableComponent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AudioSynesthesia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin CustomMeshComponent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin EditableMesh
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ChunkDownloader
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ExampleDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GooglePAD
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin GoogleCloudMessaging
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LinuxDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin IOSDeviceProfileSelector
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin LocationServicesBPLibrary
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MobilePatchingUtils
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OpenXREyeTracker
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OpenXR
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OpenXRHandTracking
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PhysXVehicles
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ProceduralMeshComponent
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PostSplashScreen
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin PropertyAccessEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin RuntimePhysXCooking
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SignificanceManager
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AndroidMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SoundFields
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WebMMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Synthesis
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin AvfMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WindowsMoviePlayer
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MediaCompositing
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ImgMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin MediaPlayerEditor
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ScreenshotTools
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WebMMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin WmfMedia
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin Takes
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ContentBrowserAssetDataSource
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ContentBrowserClassDataSource
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin ContentBrowserFileDataSource
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemGooglePlay
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OnlineSubsystemIOS
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin OculusVR
LogPluginManager: Mounting plugin SteamVR
LogInit: Warning: Incompatible or missing module: BullCowGame
LogInit: Initializing SDL.
LogInit: Initialized SDL 2.0.12 revision: 13609 (hg-13609:34cc7d3b69d3) (compiled against 2.0.12)
LogInit: Using SDL video driver 'x11'
LogInit: Display metrics:
LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayWidth: 1920
LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayHeight: 1080
LogInit:   PrimaryDisplayWorkAreaRect:
LogInit:     Left=0, Top=32, Right=1920, Bottom=1080
LogInit:   VirtualDisplayRect:
LogInit:     Left=0, Top=32, Right=1920, Bottom=1080
LogInit:   TitleSafePaddingSize: X=0.000 Y=0.000 Z=0.000 W=0.000
LogInit:   ActionSafePaddingSize: X=0.000 Y=0.000 Z=0.000 W=0.000
LogInit:   Number of monitors: 1
LogInit:     Monitor 0
LogInit:       Name: XWAYLAND0 15"
LogInit:       ID: display0
LogInit:       NativeWidth: 1920
LogInit:       NativeHeight: 1080
LogInit:       bIsPrimary: true
Running /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Linux -Project="/home/zaryob/Documents/BullCowGame-starter-kit/BullCowGame.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE

Running Mono...

Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.
Setting up Mono
~/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine ~/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux
Using 'git status' to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (/home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine).
@progress push 5%
@progress pop
ERROR: Building would modify the following engine files:
       
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/Android/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/2D/Paper2D/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/AI/AISupport/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/AI/EnvironmentQueryEditor/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Animation/LiveLink/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Blendables/LightPropagationVolume/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Cameras/CameraShakePreviewer/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Cameras/GameplayCameras/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Compression/OodleData/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Compression/OodleNetwork/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/AnimationSharing/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/CLionSourceCodeAccess/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/CodeLiteSourceCodeAccess/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/GitSourceControl/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/KDevelopSourceCodeAccess/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/NullSourceCodeAccess/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/PerforceSourceControl/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/PlasticSourceControl/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/PluginUtils/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/PropertyAccessNode/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/RiderSourceCodeAccess/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/SubversionSourceControl/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/TextureFormatOodle/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/UObjectPlugin/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Developer/VisualStudioCodeSourceCodeAccess/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/AssetManagerEditor/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/ContentBrowser/ContentBrowserAssetDataSource/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/ContentBrowser/ContentBrowserClassDataSource/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/ContentBrowser/ContentBrowserFileDataSource/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/CryptoKeys/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/CurveEditorTools/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/DataValidation/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/FacialAnimation/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/GameplayTagsEditor/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/GeometryMode/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/MaterialAnalyzer/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/MobileLauncherProfileWizard/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/PluginBrowser/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Editor/SpeedTreeImporter/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Enterprise/DatasmithContent/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Enterprise/VariantManagerContent/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/AlembicImporter/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/AutomationUtils/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/BackChannel/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/ChaosCloth/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/ChaosClothEditor/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/ChaosEditor/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/ChaosNiagara/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/ChaosSolverPlugin/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/CharacterAI/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/GeometryCache/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/GeometryCollectionPlugin/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/GeometryProcessing/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/MotoSynth/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/PlanarCutPlugin/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/PlatformCrypto/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/PythonScriptPlugin/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Experimental/SkeletalReduction/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/FX/Niagara/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Lumin/MagicLeapMedia/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Lumin/MagicLeapPassableWorld/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Media/AndroidMedia/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Media/AvfMedia/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Media/ImgMedia/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Media/MediaCompositing/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Media/MediaPlayerEditor/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Media/WebMMedia/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Media/WmfMedia/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/MeshPainting/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Messaging/TcpMessaging/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Messaging/UdpMessaging/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/MovieScene/ActorSequence/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/MovieScene/LevelSequenceEditor/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/MovieScene/MatineeToLevelSequence/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/MovieScene/TemplateSequence/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Online/OnlineSubsystem/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Online/OnlineSubsystemNull/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Online/OnlineSubsystemUtils/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Portal/LauncherChunkInstaller/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/ActorLayerUtilities/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/AndroidDeviceProfileSelector/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/AndroidPermission/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/AppleImageUtils/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/ArchVisCharacter/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/AssetTags/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/AudioCapture/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/AudioSynesthesia/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/CableComponent/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/ChunkDownloader/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/CustomMeshComponent/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/EditableMesh/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
       /home/zaryob/Development/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/Engine/Plugins/Runtime/ExampleDeviceProfileSelector/Binaries/Linux/UE4Editor.modules
LogCore: Engine exit requested (reason: EngineExit() was called)
LogExit: Preparing to exit.
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module DesktopPlatform (48)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PythonScriptPluginPreload (46)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PlatformCryptoOpenSSL (44)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PlatformCryptoTypes (42)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PlatformCrypto (40)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module OodleDataCompressionFormat (38)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AnimationModifiers (36)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AudioEditor (34)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PropertyEditor (33)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module TextureCompressor (30)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module RenderCore (28)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Landscape (26)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module SlateRHIRenderer (24)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module OpenGLDrv (22)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module AnimGraphRuntime (20)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Renderer (18)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module Engine (16)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CoreUObject (14)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module NetworkFile (12)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module CookedIterativeFile (10)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module StreamingFile (8)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module SandboxFile (6)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module PakFile (4)
LogModuleManager: Shutting down and abandoning module RSA (3)
LogExit: Exiting.
LogInit: Tearing down SDL.
Log file closed, 11/03/21 13:44:42
```

Comment: ubuntu not fedora but maybe this will help https://community.gamedev.tv/t/unable-to-run-bull-and-cow-game-on-linux-ubuntu/155138/3

Comment: Use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Answer (score 1):

I find solution. After project files generation, I open code in Visual Studio Code Editor. It makes engine compability. And project is also need to opened from Debug part of game  with selecting configuration named `<ProjectName>Editor`